# Where should I travel to see this building?

Tags: identify-this, architecture, locate-this, eastern-europe

Today I saw a picture of a building that claims to be the biggest building in the world. I really doubt that, but the problem is, I couldn't verify it. Here it is:

[image]

It is somewhere in Eastern Europe, probably a capital. So where should I travel to, when I want to see this building?

Comment: @hippietrail: Hmm, shouldn't questions be tagged based on information in the *question* itself, not on whatever turns out in the answer? (I mean the [romania] and [bucharest] tags.)

Comment: Aww, how'd I miss this earlier, I've BEEN there! :(

Comment: @Jonik: Why? Tags are to help find, group, associate relevant QAs - what do you think they are for?

Comment: @hippietrail It's just the practice we used so far. I created a metapost to discuss this: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/should-tags-reflect-the-original-question-or-the-answers-as-well

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is the [Palace of the Parliament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_of_the_Parliament) in Bucharest, Romania ([some more photos](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPalace_of_the_Parliament_of_Romania)).

As to whether it's the biggest building in the world, Wikipedia says:

> According to the World Records Academy, the Palace is the world's
>   largest civilian building, most expensive administrative building, and
>   heaviest building.

But see also the [list of largest buildings in the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_buildings_in_the_world) where it is only mentioned as the **largest parliament building** in the world.

Comment: I've heard that a similar building in Pyongyang, North Korea is the only one bigger than this.

Comment: The Boeing factory here in Everett, WA, USA, a privately owned factory that produces airliners, isn't a "civilian" building? That strikes me as strange.